# Azure Storage Connection String primary key in Azure Mobile Backend

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I want to create a key in my mobile app backend that contains my storage account primary key like [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-blob-storage/#prerequisites) tutorial instructs, but I can't figure out where in the Azure Portal I should create the key. I can't find the Connection Strings blade that the tutorial refers to. Am I missing something, or should I use the storage account primary key somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the key from portal, instead of creating it yourself.

[image]

The Azure storage connection string is like this,

**Standard**

`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=myAccount;AccountKey=myKey;`

**Secure**

`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myAccount;AccountKey=myKey;`

---

**Update**:

This should be what you are looking for,

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already knew how to get the Azure storage connection string.

According to the tutorial I linked I need to create a new key in my **mobile backend** named MS_AzureStorageAccountConnectionString using the value copied from my storage account. I can't figure out where in the **mobile backend** I need to create the key...

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can right click the project and select **properties**.  In the **Settings** page, create a **Connection string** type setting, name it MS_AzureStorageAccountConnectionString  and assign the value. Or you can manually add it in `Web.config`, under the node `<connectionStrings></connectionStrings>`.

Comment: This entire time I thought I was supposed to be looking for something in the Azure Portal, but now I understand.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it's not a setting in VS, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Okay. I couldn't find it the first time because I was looking in my app's backend's blade. I should've instead been looking in my mobile app's blade.  Backend blade/mobile app blade = two different things.

Comment: You should set it in the App Settings page in the Azure Portal for your Mobile App. Open your Mobile App, and on the Settings Page, click **Application Settings**, and add it in the **App Settings** section.